# Necesito formular una expresion regular que valide emails

Tags: python, regex

Necesito formular una expresion regular que valide emails en python (3) ..pero estoy un poco perdido en el tema de expresiones regulares.... y he leido sobre el cuidado que hay que tener a la hora de usarlas... gracias

Comment: Aquí tienes la expresión en Perl, en Python debería ser similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703864/regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-in-perl. Empieza por `[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\
xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xf
f\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\x
ff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015
"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*)*")[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\
xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*`

Comment: Ahora más en serio, revisa [help], [faq] y [ask]. En concreto, aquí se espera que describas un problema y expliques qué has intentado y qué pasa con tu código. Para hacer búsquedas, puedes probar este sitio https://www.google.es que suele ir bien.

Comment: Un ejemplo minimalista: `^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`       RegEx para email según w3.org
`^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$`       y  Una implementación del Estandard Official: RFC 5322: 
( valida en el 99.99% de los emails existentes )
`^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta brutalidad la saqué hace mucho tiempo del foro inglés y es el que uso para validar mis correos. Nunca me ha fallado

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Aquí te dejo cómo se ve de forma gráfica la validación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]